# CSS - Add a list within another styled list without using its styling

Tags: html, css, list, class

Okay, allow me to explain.

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul class="children">
   <li class="bypostauthor">
    This image should have borders:
    <img width="67" height="67" src="http://i.imgur.com/BRUVD7s.jpg">
    <ul class="children">
     <li>
      This should NOT have borders:
      <img width="67" height="67" src="http://i.imgur.com/BRUVD7s.jpg"> 
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And CSS:

```
.bypostauthor img{
 border:5px solid red;
}
```

I want to add a border to the image in the list class `bypostauthor`, not the image inside the list within it.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69AYp/1/) for example.

Unfortunately, I cannot add a unique class to the images itself. Only to the parent list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Change:**

```
.bypostauthor img{
    border:5px solid red;
}
```

**To:**

```
.bypostauthor > img{
    border:5px solid red;
}
```

See [Child Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)

Comment: You need to ***replace*** the style. If you've done that already, then the only other issue could be a conflicting style definition.

Comment: Not strange, that's how child selectors work. They ***only*** match children (not grand children). see http://jsfiddle.net/69AYp/8/

Answer (score 0):

Use a child combinator selector like this:

```
.bypostauthor > img{
 border:5px solid red;
}
```

This is different from a descendant selector which is what you have, and is applied only to the first child level element.